# How to make boostrap button full width?

Tags: html, css, button, width

I have trouble making my button full width in the form.
Also I want the button to be aligned with the forms bottom, so it takes 100% of white space in width and in the bottom.

I suppose Im having some sort of trouble with some of the containers so it cant be scaled properly with standard full width options?

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.forma {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  max-width: 450px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 700px;
}

.fa-container {
  float: left;
  background-color: #0975BB;
  width: 10%;
  height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
  position: relative;
}

i {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.form-control {
  border-radius: 0%;
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0975BB;
  border-style: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css " integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>

<div class="forma shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">

  <img class="top-logo" src="images/csd.png">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="fa-container">
        <i class="fas fa-key"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Šifra">

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="fa-container">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="password" class="form-control btn-block" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Lozinka">
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ">Sign In</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: I found the example picture. Here is the update. I need it to look like this: https://imgur.com/COjF0TN

Answer (score 0):

The CSS should be written in an `<style>` tag or in a separate file.

The code is working fine. The button if full width too.

Check it out live here: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/rNVWEEX

**EDIT**

To do so remove `p-3` and `mb-5` class from the div with class `.forma`.

And do not give the form a fixed height.

See here: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/zYGogBG

Comment: ok. I will try to change it

Yea it is full width of the container. I want to expand its right and left side to the end of the form to fill the white space between the form and buttons border.

Comment: Check it out live here: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/rNVWEEX

Comment: Example picture in comments under my post.

Comment: Ok, that can be done by removing 'p-3 mb-5' class from the div with class .forma .

Comment: And do not give the form a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 has a class pre-defined for this add "btn-block" to the button class

btn-block adds the below CSS styles

```
display: block;
width: 100%;
```

Below is an example of how to get it close to what you have linked

```css
        body {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
        }

        .forma {
            margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
            max-width: 450px;
            width: 450px;
            height: 300px;
        }

        .fa-container {

            float: left;
            background-color: #0975BB;
            width: 10%;
            height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
            position: relative;

        }

        i {
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .form-control {
            border-radius: 0%;
            float: left;
            width: 90%;
            margin-bottom: 25px;
        }


        .btn {
            border-radius: 0%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #0975BB;
            border-style: hidden;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body style="margin-top: 200px;">
    <div class="forma shadow mb-5 bg-white rounded">

        <img class="top-logo" src="images/csd.png">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group p-3">

                <div class="fa-container">
                    <i class="fas fa-key"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                    placeholder="Šifra">

            </div>

            <div class="form-group p-3">
                <div class="fa-container">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="password" class="form-control btn-block" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Lozinka">
            </div>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ">Sign In</button>
        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: Example picture in comments under my post.

Comment: Just need to do some restructuring of your HTML - have a div inside the form which holds the input fields and the button outside of this div (i'll add an example to my answer)